# Error when call model in Layout.cshtml Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index.cshtml view that I use a model to create a dropdown list .
But I want to use the same model in Layout.cshtml and to do the same and I'm getting this error I would like to know what can I do different to fix it. My idea is reuse the same view model from the Index on the Layout view.

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable <SelectListItem>
<select id="subSectionID"
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
}
</select>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable <SelectListItem>
<select id="subSectionID"
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
}
</select>
```

Controller

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
          var subSections = await UtilityResource.GetSubSections();

          var subSectionList = subSections.Select(c => new SelectListItem()

            {
                Text = c.Name,
                Value = c.Id.ToString()

            }).ToList();
            subSectionList = subSectionList.OrderBy(c => c.Text).ToList();
           
            return View(subSectionList);
        }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel 
    {
        public int SelectedSubSectionId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubSections { get; set; }

        public List<VisitVM> VisitVMList { get; set; }

        public string SubSectionName { get; set; }
         
    }
    
}
```

Error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.

Comment: What is a controller for an index action?

Comment: @Serge  Yes, in the index it works correctly but I would like to reuse this controller to use the same list in the Layout.

Comment: I was asking what is the controller name? You must be having several index pages

Comment: It called Home Controller and inside it is Index Method

Comment: Do you have a viewmodel class?

Comment: Yes I have too is this one :

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedSubSectionId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubSections { get; set; }

        public List<VisitVM> VisitVMList { get; set; }

        public string SubSectionName { get; set; }
      
    }
    
}

Comment: I added the view model on above sorry I forgot!

Comment: What actions  are you using ViewModel? Can you check it in VS by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the action

```
var viewModel= new ViewModel{ SubSections = subSectionList};
return View(viewModel);
```

and Layout and Index views should have this code

```
@model ViewModel

....

 <select class="form-control" id="subSectionID" 
         asp-for="@Model.SelectedSubSectionId" asp-items="@Model.SubSections">
         <option value="0" >Select</option>
 </select>
```